# Can a PHP class file name be assigned to a variable and be called with new?

Tags: php, class

I have the following snippet from [here](http://phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html).

```
/*** a new controller class instance ***/
$class = $this->controller . 'Controller';

$controller = new $class($this->registry);
```

In the code above.  How does the first line work?  It looks like it is assigning a filename to the variable `$class`, a regular string.  I understand what it is doing, but don't understand the syntax and PHP rule here.

If I use,

```
echo $class;
```

I get "indexController" as expected, but again that's a file name.

Comment: It's not a filename that it's assigning to $class, it's a class name. A filename would typically end in `.php`, but your code probably also has an autoloader that loads a file based on that class name

Comment: I don't know if I understood what you want, but I guess you want to understand how the naming convention works?

Comment: Read about custom autoloading in PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php
Basing on a class name (if class is not loaded yet) it tries to "find out" the file name and include this file

Answer (score 1):

```
$controller = 'Index'; //populated dynamic
$class = $controller . 'Controller';
```

It gives us

> IndexController

Now we need to check if the file exists and initialize it.

```
if(file_exists($class.'.php')){
  //Let's include the file
  include($class.'.php');
  //Check if the class exists
  if(class_exists($class)){
   new $class;
  }
}
```

This is a very basic example, but I guess this answer your question about how this works, of course in a framework it's more dynamic

//LE
So the developer will have to respect some coding standards, and naming convention in order for the "framework" to work, it will need to create a filename and append to the name in uppercase Controller and also the same thing for the class name. I guess you are new to the OOP world and I think I don't need to confuse you with more complicated examples